# Is it possible to have a System.IO.Stream as input parameter for Swagger?

Tags: asp.net, stream, swagger, swagger-ui

We're using swagger (v 2.0) for a project, and one of the ASP.NET API Controllers has a function that receives a [FromBody] System.IO.Stream. But when I start the swagger ui, the UI suggests something that when used and debugged, the stream is always null. When researching online, I see many others use IFromFile, but that seems to be .NET Core exclusive.

Is what I'm trying to do possible, or should I try something else?
Thanks in advance.

The code currently used:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Store the photo of the object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>Registers the given object photo that was captured through scanning. </remarks>
    /// <param name="barcode">Barcode of the scanned object </param>
    /// <param name="lang">Language in which the request should be processed, if possible (e.g., for object information retrieval and status message construction).  This is the MD Connect GUI’s language. Expressed as a LanguageCode (see Definitions). </param>
    /// <param name="photo"></param>
    /// <response code="201">The captured object photo was successfully registered.</response>
    /// <response code="400">Bad Request</response>
    /// <response code="500">Internal Server Error</response>
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/logistore/multiscan/scanhandler/v1/objects/{barcode}/scan/photos")]
    [SwaggerOperation("RegisterCapturedObjectPhoto")]
    [SwaggerResponse(200, type: typeof(HttpStatusCode))]
    [SwaggerResponse(201, type: typeof(HttpStatusCode))]
    [SwaggerResponse(400, type: typeof(ErrorResult))]
    [SwaggerResponse(500, type: typeof(ErrorResult))]
    public IHttpActionResult RegisterCapturedObjectPhoto([FromUri]string barcode, [FromUri]string lang, [FromBody]System.IO.Stream photo)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(barcode))
        {
            throw new RestException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "UNKNOWN_BARCODE", "Unknown barcode / Onbekende barcode: Barcode cannot be empty.");
        }

        if (photo == null)
        {
            throw new RestException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "INVALID_PHOTO", "Invalid photo / Ongeldige foto: Invalid input for photo received.");
        }

        return Content(HttpStatusCode.Created, "The captured object photo was successfully registered.");
    }
```

The Swagger UI Suggestion:

[image: The swagger UI suggestion]